# How to install existing fuelphp project from repo?

Tags: fuelphp

How to install existing fuelphp project from repo? My boss just let me update our service site and he want me to import the files from github.com. I already imported it including the database. The very big problem for me here is that I'm very much new about fuelphp and I even got a lot of problems while installing in my own, but I think I already install it correctly. And now, the repo is fuelphp and I don't know if I'm going to install or configure it. Can someone please give me steps here? Also, the repository has .mwb file (which is is a database) which make me confuse more how to run it with the database. Can anyone help me through this step by step? Very much thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what is your problem.

Comment: First, SSH into your server with a user that shares permissions with your webserver's user, and clone the project's repository. Run `php composer.phar install` (of course after you installed Composer). Then set up the database. An `mwb` file is related to MySQL Workbench, so you can use that to convert it to an `sql` file, which you can import in phpMyAdmin, if you're more familiar with that than MySQL Workbench. Your question is very specific, so these kind of questions should be rather asked on the FuelPHP forums, or even better, the FuelPHP IRC channel on freenode (#fuelphp).

Comment: Thanks @BartaTamás. I've already receive an answer on fuelphp furom. They said I need to use the migrations.